# Delphi, TTreeView: how to get the screen coordinates of the given node and its icon?

Tags: delphi, treeview, ttreenodes

Please help me to get the screen coordinates of the state icon rectangle of the given `TTreeNode` in a `TreeView` (I mean the icons specified in the `TTreeView.StateImages` property).

There is a `TTreeView.GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y: integer): : THitTests` function, but that is not quite what I'm looking for; it says whether the given coordinates correspond to the label, or to the icon, or to the state icon of the item, but I need to know what part of the icon was clicked.

(The reason is that I want to implement the `TreeView` nodes with two checkboxes for each item, and I use `StateImages` to simulate the checkboxes (one state is a checked item, the other state is an unchecked item). As I understand, to know which one of the checkboxes is clicked I need to compare the cursor coordinates with the state icon coordinates. How can I get them?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send the control a [`tvm_GetItemRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773610.aspx) message which will tell you the client coordinates of the item's bounding box. Use that and what you know of the relative positions of the label text and the icons to determine where the mouse was clicked in the icon.

Instead of `GetHitTestInfoAt`, you might prefer to send a [`tvm_HitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773732.aspx) message instead since it will give you the hit-test information and an item handle at once; a handle is what `tvm_GetItemRect` requires.

You don't need the *screen* coordinates since all the coordinates involved so far are client coordinates, but you can call [`ClientToScreen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ClientToScreen) if you really want screen coordinates.

Comment: Calling macros is much easier than sending messages. But even then, you don't need to explicitly send the `TVM_GETITEMRECT` message since Delphi has the [`TTreeNode.DisplayRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.DisplayRect) method which internally calls the corresponding `TVM_GETITEMRECT` message macro and returns the bounding rectangle for a tree node.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Here's the code I made:
`uses CommCtrl;
...
var
  R: TRect;
  pItemRect: pointer;
begin
  pItemRect := @R;
  HTREEITEM(pItemRect^) := TreeView.Selected.ItemId;
  SendMessage(TreeView1.Handle, TVM_GETITEMRECT, WParam(true), LParam(pItemRect));
...`
- that puts into `R` the coordinates of the selected item text. Thus, the right X coordinate of the icon is `R.Left - 4` (there are 3 blank pixels between the icon and the text).

Comment: Now you can simplify your code to use `TreeView.Selected.DisplayRect` because the `DisplayRect` method is merely a wrapper for the `TVM_GETITEMRECT` message. And be careful with such code because not always must be selected some node, thus the `TTreeView.Selected` may be `nil`. Anyway, if that resolved your question, don't forget to [`accept the answer`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541).

Comment: @TLama, oh yes, this method gives just the same result. Thank you! Anyway, I've had some extra practice in sending messages :)